# Guzzle Cannot make GET request to the localhost (port: 80, 8000, 8080, etc )

Tags: php, laravel, http, guzzle, laravel-artisan

Currently using Laravel 5.5 and Guzzle that comes together with the laravel installer.

I am trying to make GET request (error occur with other HTTP requests as well) but don't seem work.

This code does not work:

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
    $code = $request->code;

    $client = new Client(['exceptions' => false]);

    try {
      $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost/api/tests');
        // $response = $http->request('POST', Config::get('app.url') . '/oauth/token', [
        //     'form_params' => [
        //         'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        //         'client_id' => Config::get('oauth_client.client_id'),
        //         'client_secret' => Config::get('oauth_client.client_secret'),
        //         'redirect_uri' => Config::get('oauth_client.redirect_uri'),
        //         'code' => $code,
        //     ],
        // ]);
        // return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
    dd($response->getBody());
    return;
}
```

But this code below is work very well

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
    $code = $request->code;

    $client = new Client(['exceptions' => false]);

    try {
      $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.google.co.id');
        // $response = $http->request('POST', Config::get('app.url') . '/oauth/token', [
        //     'form_params' => [
        //         'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        //         'client_id' => Config::get('oauth_client.client_id'),
        //         'client_secret' => Config::get('oauth_client.client_secret'),
        //         'redirect_uri' => Config::get('oauth_client.redirect_uri'),
        //         'code' => $code,
        //     ],
        // ]);
        // return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
    dd($response->getBody());
    return;
}
```

I'm not understand why my Guzzle able to request to google.com but unable to connect to my own localhost server (to all ports).

Any help will greatly appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: is your server running? can you access it via browser?

Comment: What errors are you getting? And whats with all the commented code?

Comment: yeah, development server is running

Comment: no error, but the browser keep loading then freeze

Comment: Dump `dd($e->getMessage());` instead.

Comment: Also I got a feeling your calling this page from itself which is causing an infinite loop.

Comment: Also its unclear what your asking, where are you calling different ports other then 80?

Comment: I can open it using browser/postman pretty well

Comment: I just realize it's not about port, I tried some different ports and result is same issue.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46284277/7663972) can help.

Comment: I think best solution is using Apache and virtual host in my development laptop.

Comment: Is there answer for this question???? im desperate for having 504 gateway time out nginx for request own localhost

Comment: @NasihunAminSuhardiyan have you tried to access the end point using postman ? does it work ? if yes, check your endpoint port it should be on port 80 or guzzle will error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Apache2 and Virtual Host for my development server solved the problem, this approach more realistic than making any changes on my Guzzle parameters.

So my conclusion is Better to use real web server (Nginx, Apache) rather than artisan serve.

Answer (score 8):

The reason why it does not work is that `php artisan serve` uses the PHP built-in web server and this is [single threaded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). So if you run your application it cannot make another request (your Guzzle request) until it finishes the initial request. That is why it hangs (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1857#issuecomment-506962175)).

One solution is (as you pointed out) to use a real webserver that is multi-threaded.

But if you still want to use `php artisan serve` instead of a web server like Nginx, there is an easy solution (that I already posted in [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57572727/5816097)):

You could run another web server instance with another port and configure your application to use this `base_uri` when connecting to your API:

```
php artisan serve \\ defaults to port 8000
\\ in another console
php artisan serve --port=8001
```

```php
$client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8001/api/tests')
```

Comment: This helped - Hadn't considered the builtin server being single threaded and trying to nest requests.

Comment: for php7.4 we can user the following command: PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS=10 php artisan serve --port=80 --host 0.0.0.0

Answer (score -2):

set `'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER'` option to false

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
    $code = $request->code;

    $client = new Client(['exceptions' => false, 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' => false]);

    try {
      $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost/api/tests');
        // $response = $http->request('POST', Config::get('app.url') . '/oauth/token', [
        //     'form_params' => [
        //         'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        //         'client_id' => Config::get('oauth_client.client_id'),
        //         'client_secret' => Config::get('oauth_client.client_secret'),
        //         'redirect_uri' => Config::get('oauth_client.redirect_uri'),
        //         'code' => $code,
        //     ],
        // ]);
        // return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }
    dd($response->getBody());
    return;
}
```