# Cannot make request internally to my symfony application served on localhost:8000

Tags: php, docker, symfony, symfony-http-client

I have Symfony application running through docker.

It served on http://localhost:8000/. I'm trying to test my API routes, for example to check if they are available when JWT provided or not, check status code and so on.

Here is sample code that I have:

```
class SampleTest extends TestCase
{
    private $client;   
    
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->client = (new HttpClient())::create();
    }
    
    public function testSampleTest(): void
    {
        $this->client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8000/api/test-json');
    }
}
```

anyway I'm getting this of error:

`Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Exception\TransportException: Couldn't connect to server for "http://localhost:8000/api/test-json".`

As it's mentioned here [Guzzle Cannot make GET request to the localhost (port: 80, 8000, 8080, etc )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841018/guzzle-cannot-make-get-request-to-the-localhost-port-80-8000-8080-etc) it is impossible to make requests to localhost.

But how can I solve it when I have application in docker container? Is there any standard solution for such case in Symfony ecosystem?

Comment: Could you provide minimal information about your Docker setup ?

Comment: @GregoireDucharme same result for 127.0.0.1. Anyway I don't want to care about base_url in any case, I mean It should be done in some automated way I think

Comment: @AymDev what kind of information do you mean?

Comment: @AndriiSukhoi *"I have symfony application running through docker"* -> how ?

Comment: @AymDev I have docker-compose.yml for it. And there are services

Comment: Next time share the relevant parts of your docker-compose.yml before the question gets closed. We can't guess what are your services or what is your networking configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239911/discussion-between-andrii-sukhoi-and-aymdev).